# Django ReportLab Timezone

Tags: django, timezone, reportlab

I'm using ReportLab in Django.  I have a model with the following field:

```
time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And my `TIME_ZONE` variable in settings.py is set to:

```
Africa/Johannesburg
```

I use a formset to populate this model.  The time_stamp field saves correctly with the correct time zone, but when I place the time_stamp in my ReportLab pdf, the time zone is set to UTC.

For example:
`time_stamp` in the saved model (as `str(time_stamp)[:19]` is:

```
2015-03-04 07:57:28
```

But `time_stamp` in pdf document (as `str(time_stamp)[:19]` is:

```
2015-03-04 05:57:28
```

Exactly 2 hours earlier (Africa/Johannesburg is UTC + 2hours).

How can I set the time zone for ReportLab?  Should it be specified in settings.py or in views.py while generating the pdf?  If there is no solution, how do I add 2 hours to the `time_stamp`?

Some answers suggested changing `auto_now_add=True` with `default=datetime.datetime.now()`, but this creates a warning while migrating the database (Naive expression used).

Comment: What's the value of USE_TZ in your settings?

Comment: Did not notice the setting - changed it to USE_TZ=False and it works!  Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a user of Reportlab but in general I don't think setting USE_TZ=False is the right approach to solve your problem. Set it back to True and instead of truncating your time stamp yourself like:

```
str(time_stamp)[:19]
```

You should try applying Django's [date template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) in your template, e.g.:

```
{{ time_stamp|date:"SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT" }}
```

It can be confusing how Django is handling timezones. But it's best practice to save timestamps in your database in UTC. You may want to refer to Django's timezone FAQ:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones-faq